# Raven Matrix-like tests

Tags: pattern

I have some Raven test that I couldn't find the answers
Hope you can find the answers.

I found this test in [this IQ Test application](https://cafebazaar.ir/app/com.hotmail.at.miladmolaee.IQTest).

[image: Raven test 1]

[image: Raven test 2]

[image: Raven test 3]

[image: Raven test 4]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Middle is like "mirror" - or "Axial symmetry" if you like. So bottom left.
2) Similar puzzle answered [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/76138/3-iq-test-patterns). Top right seems correct one - You count numbers each squares, and 1 yellow + 2 blue and 3 purple is missing. Same for each sides - three left, three bottom and two right, so it has to "stick" to right side of box.
3) Answered [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/69982/mensa-sample-iq-test-question)
4) Seems like <-> is symbol like in first one as "mirror", and simple arrow is "expansion in that direction", so bottom right seems like a correct answer.